# Module to import discounts/coupons to prestashop

Tags: csv, import, prestashop, coupon, discounts

I have csv/xls file with multiple coupons codes from my store and I want to import it to my online prestashop 1.6 all at once. All discounts rules will be the same.

I found some modules on addons, but can't pick up one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you to use this module https://addons.prestashop.com/en/promotions-gifts/29454-discounts-coupons-manager-generate-and-import.html

It perfectly adjust to your needs and able to create multiple instances of the same discount with unique codes in one click